# have an element stay stickied over another full width element

Tags: html, css

I need to create form that stays stickied when scrolling through a new full width element.

On this site, you can see it in action: https://www.pillpack.com/how-it-works but after inspecting the elements, I still cant see how they achieve this effect.

Here is what my layout currently looks like:

[image]

The red rectangle is stickied and when scrolling, it will stick to the top of the viewport. The problem I am facing here is that I need the red rectangle to stay stickied even when reaching the green portion.

The way I am currently achieving this effect is essentially 2 columns within a parent container. The parent container is flexing its children elements and the red rectangle has position sticky. But now I have a full width element that my red rectangle still needs to stay sticky on.

Would love some insight on this.

EDIT:

some basic psuedo-esque code for you...

```
HTML

section.wrapper
  div.container
    div.left
    form
section.wrapper.green-bg
  div.container
    div.left
```

```
CSS

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.form {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Hopefully you guys can understand the problem here. `sections` are full width elements. Inside `sections`, theres a `div.container` which has a max-width and is centered. Within the `container` is where the content goes.

The first section needs to have no background but the second section needs a green background. Since the background is full-width, it needs to be done on the `section` element. This causes problems because for the red rectangle to be stickied, all elements needs to be inside a parent container.

Comment: You need to share some of your code

Comment: This is more of a: answer if you know it kinda deal. I don't think adding my own code would help much here but I did... This aint some basic frontend question

Answer (score 1):

It's because your form is nested inside a separate wrapper from your green area. The sticky form and the green area need to be encompassed by the same parent element.

Basic example: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hoover-mdy4t

Comment: I understand why my stuff isnt working. I was just curious how pillpack achieves this effect and what would be the best way to implement it myself. Although your codesandbox does what I am looking for, I try not to use floats when I can. If I still can't get this to work, ill mark yours as correct. Appreciate your input.

Comment: The floats shouldn't have anything to do with "stickiness". Just a quick way to position things for the demo. There are a lot of tutorials online showing how the sticky toolbar affect can be achieved. A rudimentary example can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: Doesnt float play a major role in your example?

Comment: Also, do you think you can add in the `container` and `wrapper` classes in your example? I've been playing around with your example and adding in max-width breaks everything. I can add a container to the full width element but i cant do it around the first section: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-surf-5vyy2